# For loop counter not incrementing

Tags: python

I have a double for loop to go through a matrix and compare numbers. The `RowCounter` is not incremented in my loop and I can't see why. I also recreated the spaces in front of every line, in order to have nothing "broken" by this part. In Notepad++ I get therefore that "plus-sign" in front of the first `for`-loop, so that I can close the whole loops and what is inside. Basically my 2 `for`-loops do this:

```
RowCounter=0 ColCounter=0
RowCounter=0 ColCounter=1
RowCounter=0 ColCounter=2
RowCounter=0 ColCounter=3
RowCounter=0 ColCounter=0
RowCounter=0 ColCounter=1
RowCounter=0 ColCounter=2
RowCounter=0 ColCounter=3
```

I really do not understand why the `RowCounter` is not raised to 1.

```
Rows=2
Cols=5
for RowCounter in range(0, Rows-1, 1):
    for ColCounter in range(0, Cols-1, 1):
        CurrentValue=float(Numbers[RowCounter][ColCounter])                  
        if CurrentValue==NoDataValue:
            DataMatrix[RowCounter][ColCounter]=float(0.0)
        else:
            DataMatrix[RowCounter][ColCounter]=float(CurrentValue)
```

Comment: `range(0, Rows-1, 1)` => `range(0, 1, 1)` 1 is not inclusive in range. Remove `-1`

Comment: the last integer generated by range() is up to, but not including, stop. For example range(0, 5) generates integers from 0 up to, but not including, 5. Your first for_loop generates only 0.

Comment: Better yet, just use `range(Rows)` (and `range(Cols)`)—that's all that's required in those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `class range(start, stop[, step])`
>
> [...]
>
> For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and r[i] < stop.

[Python3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

From an usage perspective, `for x in range(start, stop, step)` could be explained as following:

```
# This is an explanation, use for ... in range
x = start
while x < stop:
     # ...
     x += step
```

Your stop boundary is therefore wrong.